# Plugging Shure 520DX harmonica mic straight into audio interface

Tags: microphones, audio

I plan to buy Shure 520DX microphone and plugging it straight into my audio interface. Do I need to add an amp simulation plugin in the signal chain to achieve the desirable sound or will it sound good by itself?

It's a mic with a jack connection for use with amps and this made me wonder.

Will the sound without the amp will be as distorted as when I play guitar with just an amp and without a cabinet?

Also, I believe I'll have to switch from mic/line mode to instrument mode since this microphone needs at least 100k impendance load

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, you are correct that the Shure 520DX requires the high impedence 'Instrument' input.

I don't know what sound you want.  Fortunately, as this is going into a recording input, you don't have to decide yet.  Record it clean.  If you want a different sound, try some plugins while mixing.  MAYBE if you consistently decide on the same plugin, same settings, you can save a bit of time by putting them in an input channel of your DAW.

Comment: Thanks for the help. I wonder if minimum 100k ohm load needed for this microphone will work well with my 1 milion ohm instrument load in the interface though.

Comment: That will be fine.